# Why is IEnumerable's generic parameter covariant, and IList's is not?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-collections

Why is IEnumerable's generic parameter covariant, and IList's is not? So that, given this:

```
class base1 {}
class derived : base1 {}

var list1 = new List<derived>();
```

I can do this:

```
IEnumerable<base1> list3 = list1;
```

But can't do this:

```
IList<base1> list2 = list1;
```

I just wonder why the restriction on IList which is derived from IEnumerable, which is covariant